# Issues in Go with JSON unmarshal of map[string]int64

Tags: json, dictionary, parsing, go

I am having issue with JSON unmarshal to a Go structure. Visibly the source of the issue is understable - a string is coming for the int64, except that I am not finding ways to solve it without changing the datatype of Count to map[string]string. I saw similar discussions on SO, but they didn't help much. Here is a representative code and the issue. Please suggest how I can get through.

```golang
type Product struct {
    Count  map[string]int64 `json:",string"`
}

func main() {
    s := `{"count":{"FAN":"58"}}`

    var pro Product
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(s), &pro)
    if err == nil {
        fmt.Printf("%+v\n", pro)
    } else {
        fmt.Println(err)
        fmt.Printf("%+v\n", pro)
    }
}
```

Output:

> json: cannot unmarshal string into Go struct field Product.Count of type int64
>   {Count:map[FAN:0]}

Comment: seems like "58" is a string and not an int64 as specified by `Count`.

Comment: go doc encoding/json.Number

Comment: The downvotes strike me as rather harsh: Given that `,string` exists, this seems like something that could potentially work, and there's [a similarly fair question on how to do this with slices](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49415573/5085211) instead of maps.

Answer (score 2):

As you've noted yourself, this is happening because you are not passing in the JSON integer `58`, but a JSON string `"58"`.

If you modify your example input to

```
s := `{"count":{"FAN":58}}`
```

then your code [works as expected](https://play.golang.org/p/TZvLgvXDjfZ).

You could write a custom unmarshaller, but fixing the issue while unmarshalling might not be what you want; rather find a way to modify your data pipeline and ensure that the JSON object is sanitized properly. Or, if that's impossible, do as you suggest yourself and use a `map[string]string` instead, then fix up the data types after unmashalling.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, changing the struct seems to be the way to go.